# How to solve this "Synchronize on a new "Object" instead. "

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I am getting the warning in sonar at line synchronized (new Integer(count)) as
Synchronize on a new "Object" instead.

```
public class PRMDataTransferHelper {

    /** static variable to keep count */
    private static int count = 0;

    private static void done() {

        synchronized (new Integer(count)) {
            count--;

            if (0 == count) {
                cleanUp();
            }
        }

        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: As @MarkusFischer notes, `synchronized (new <anything>)` does not make any(\*) sense because it basically synchronizes on an object only existent in the current thread, i.e. it makes sure the current thread does not run concurrently with itself which, by definition, can never happen anyway. (* The synchronization may still imply a memory barrier, but that's usually not what one actually is out for.)

Comment: Note that for your special use case an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) will do exactly what you need without the need for additional synchronization on your side.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here:

1. As Sonar states, you shouldn't synchronize on a primitive wrapper (i.e. Integer, Long, Boolean, etc.) since these can be created by autoboxing, and Sonar assumes that this is risky. It is risky because a lock object used in a `synchronized` statement should be constant among all threads that are to be synchronized. Any dynamic object that may be re-used in the program logic can easily lead to failed synchronization. Therefore, it is best practise to instantiate Object and create a special lock object that is used for synchronization only.
2. You are using `new Integer(count)`, i.e. whenever the `synchronized` block is entered, a new instance of integer is created. This means that each thread will see its own version of a lock object, and thus the block will not be synchronized between threads at all. In order to achieve synchronization, you need to re-use a lock object shared by all threads.

In your case, having a static variable such as

```
private static Object lock=new Object();
```

and using this one in `synchronized(lock)` would ensure that all threads are indeed synchronized at the beginning of the block.